# Logging at the end of building docs with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

#### Some Background:

While building the documentation of a library with sphinx I measure some rendering times (for rendering videos with that library) using a custom Directive and save them to an csv file. To get a readable log I don't want to print them right away, but as soon as a all of them have been run, for example right at the end of the build log. I already have a script producing that rendering summary.

#### The actual question:

Where do I need to call my logging script so that it is executed once after the step "reading sources" is done? I don't really care about the exact position at which it is added to the log.

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of one of the core events defined by Sphinx: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx-core-events

Comment: Make it an answer and I would approve it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx defines several *events* that can be used to trigger event handlers (via a `setup()` function). I am not sure which event is most suitable in your case, but here is the list of core events:

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx-core-events